# How to bind the figure produced by xplot.plotly in F# to WPF

Tags: wpf, f#

I want to bind the surface figure in wpf widget， and I find the xplot.plotly.WPF. Here is the situation, I can show the figure in Web using the test code. However, I cant "open xplot.plotly.WPF" cause "there is no WPF".

xplot.plotly.WPF-version 1.3
xplot.plotly -version 2.0

```ml
open XPlot.Plotly

let z =
    [
        [27.80985; 49.61936; 83.08067; 116.6632; 130.414; 150.7206; 220.1871; 156.1536; 148.6416; 203.7845; 206.0386; 107.1618; 68.36975; 45.3359; 49.96142; 21.89279; 17.02552; 11.74317; 14.75226; 13.6671; 5.677561; 3.31234; 1.156517; -0.147662]
        [27.71966; 48.55022; 65.21374; 95.27666; 116.9964; 133.9056; 152.3412; 151.934; 160.1139; 179.5327; 147.6184; 170.3943; 121.8194; 52.58537; 33.08871; 38.40972; 44.24843; 69.5786; 4.019351; 3.050024; 3.039719; 2.996142; 2.967954; 1.999594]
        [30.4267; 33.47752; 44.80953; 62.47495; 77.43523; 104.2153; 102.7393; 137.0004; 186.0706; 219.3173; 181.7615; 120.9154; 143.1835; 82.40501; 48.47132; 74.71461; 60.0909; 7.073525; 6.089851; 6.53745; 6.666096; 7.306965; 5.73684; 3.625628]
        [16.66549; 30.1086; 39.96952; 44.12225; 59.57512; 77.56929; 106.8925; 166.5539; 175.2381; 185.2815; 154.5056; 83.0433; 62.61732; 62.33167; 60.55916; 55.92124; 15.17284; 8.248324; 36.68087; 61.93413; 20.26867; 68.58819; 46.49812; 0.2360095]
        [8.815617; 18.3516; 8.658275; 27.5859; 48.62691; 60.18013; 91.3286; 145.7109; 116.0653; 106.2662; 68.69447; 53.10596; 37.92797; 47.95942; 47.42691; 69.20731; 44.95468; 29.17197; 17.91674; 16.25515; 14.65559; 17.26048; 31.22245; 46.71704]
        [6.628881; 10.41339; 24.81939; 26.08952; 30.1605; 52.30802; 64.71007; 76.30823; 84.63686; 99.4324; 62.52132; 46.81647; 55.76606; 82.4099; 140.2647; 81.26501; 56.45756; 30.42164; 17.28782; 8.302431; 2.981626; 2.698536; 5.886086; 5.268358]
        [21.83975; 6.63927; 18.97085; 32.89204; 43.15014; 62.86014; 104.6657; 130.2294; 114.8494; 106.9873; 61.89647; 55.55682; 86.80986; 89.27802; 122.4221; 123.9698; 109.0952; 98.41956; 77.61374; 32.49031; 14.67344; 7.370775; 0.03711011; 0.6423392]
        [53.34303; 26.79797; 6.63927; 10.88787; 17.2044; 56.18116; 79.70141; 90.8453; 98.27675; 80.87243; 74.7931; 75.54661; 73.4373; 74.11694; 68.1749; 46.24076; 39.93857; 31.21653; 36.88335; 40.02525; 117.4297; 12.70328; 1.729771; 0.]
        [25.66785; 63.05717; 22.1414; 17.074; 41.74483; 60.27227; 81.42432; 114.444; 102.3234; 101.7878; 111.031; 119.2309; 114.0777; 110.5296; 59.19355; 42.47175; 14.63598; 6.944074; 6.944075; 27.74936; 0.; 0.; 0.09449376; 0.07732264]
        [12.827; 69.20554; 46.76293; 13.96517; 33.88744; 61.82613; 84.74799; 121.122; 145.2741; 153.1797; 204.786; 227.9242; 236.3038; 228.3655; 79.34425; 25.93483; 6.944074; 6.944074; 6.944075; 7.553681; 0.; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 68.66396; 59.0435; 33.35762; 47.45282; 57.8355; 78.91689; 107.8275; 168.0053; 130.9597; 212.5541; 165.8122; 210.2429; 181.1713; 189.7617; 137.3378; 84.65395; 8.677168; 6.956576; 8.468093; 0.; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 95.17499; 80.03818; 59.89862; 39.58476; 50.28058; 63.81641; 80.61302; 66.37824; 198.7651; 244.3467; 294.2474; 264.3517; 176.4082; 60.21857; 77.41475; 53.16981; 56.16393; 6.949235; 7.531059; 3.780177; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 134.9879; 130.3696; 96.86325; 75.70494; 58.86466; 57.20374; 55.18837; 78.128; 108.5582; 154.3774; 319.1686; 372.8826; 275.4655; 130.2632; 54.93822; 25.49719; 8.047439; 8.084393; 5.115252; 5.678269; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 48.08919; 142.5558; 140.3777; 154.7261; 87.9361; 58.11092; 52.83869; 67.14822; 83.66798; 118.9242; 150.0681; 272.9709; 341.1366; 238.664; 190.2; 116.8943; 91.48672; 14.0157; 42.29277; 5.115252; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 54.1941; 146.3839; 99.48143; 96.19411; 102.9473; 76.14089; 57.7844; 47.0402; 64.36799; 84.23767; 162.7181; 121.3275; 213.1646; 328.482; 285.4489; 283.8319; 212.815; 164.549; 92.29631; 7.244015; 1.167; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 6.919659; 195.1709; 132.5253; 135.2341; 89.85069; 89.45549; 60.29967; 50.33806; 39.17583; 59.06854; 74.52159; 84.93402; 187.1219; 123.9673; 103.7027; 128.986; 165.1283; 249.7054; 95.39966; 10.00284; 2.39255; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 21.73871; 123.1339; 176.7414; 158.2698; 137.235; 105.3089; 86.63255; 53.11591; 29.03865; 30.40539; 39.04902; 49.23405; 63.27853; 111.4215; 101.1956; 40.00962; 59.84565; 74.51253; 17.06316; 2.435141; 2.287471; -0.0003636982; 0.]
        [0.; 0.; 62.04672; 136.3122; 201.7952; 168.1343; 95.2046; 58.90624; 46.94091; 49.27053; 37.10416; 17.97011; 30.93697; 33.39257; 44.03077; 55.64542; 78.22423; 14.42782; 9.954997; 7.768213; 13.0254; 21.73166; 2.156372; 0.5317867]
        [0.; 0.; 79.62993; 139.6978; 173.167; 192.8718; 196.3499; 144.6611; 106.5424; 57.16653; 41.16107; 32.12764; 13.8566; 10.91772; 12.07177; 22.38254; 24.72105; 6.803666; 4.200841; 16.46857; 15.70744; 33.96221; 7.575688; -0.04880907]
        [0.; 0.; 33.2664; 57.53643; 167.2241; 196.4833; 194.7966; 182.1884; 119.6961; 73.02113; 48.36549; 33.74652; 26.2379; 16.3578; 6.811293; 6.63927; 6.639271; 8.468093; 6.194273; 3.591233; 3.81486; 8.600739; 5.21889; 0.]
        [0.; 0.; 29.77937; 54.97282; 144.7995; 207.4904; 165.3432; 171.4047; 174.9216; 100.2733; 61.46441; 50.19171; 26.08209; 17.18218; 8.468093; 6.63927; 6.334467; 6.334467; 5.666687; 4.272203; 0.; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 0.; 31.409; 132.7418; 185.5796; 121.8299; 185.3841; 160.6566; 116.1478; 118.1078; 141.7946; 65.56351; 48.84066; 23.13864; 18.12932; 10.28531; 6.029663; 6.044627; 5.694764; 3.739085; 3.896037; 0.; 0.; 0.]
        [0.; 0.; 19.58994; 42.30355; 96.26777; 187.1207; 179.6626; 221.3898; 154.2617; 142.1604; 148.5737; 67.17937; 40.69044; 39.74512; 26.10166; 14.48469; 8.65873; 3.896037; 3.571392; 3.896037; 3.896037; 3.896037; 1.077756; 0.]
        [0.001229679; 3.008948; 5.909858; 33.50574; 104.3341; 152.2165; 198.1988; 191.841; 228.7349; 168.1041; 144.2759; 110.7436; 57.65214; 42.63504; 27.91891; 15.41052; 8.056102; 3.90283; 3.879774; 3.936718; 3.968634; 0.1236256; 3.985531; -0.1835741]
        [0.; 5.626141; 7.676256; 63.16226; 45.99762; 79.56688; 227.311; 203.9287; 172.5618; 177.1462; 140.4554; 123.9905; 110.346; 65.12319; 34.31887; 24.5278; 9.561069; 3.334991; 5.590495; 5.487353; 5.909499; 5.868994; 5.833817; 3.568177]
    ]

(**
Plotly 3D Surface Plots
=======================
[Full source and data](https://github.com/fslaborg/XPlot/blob/master/docsrc/content/chart/plotly-3d-surface-plots.fsx)
Topographical 3D Surface Plot
-----------------------------
*)

(*** define-output: chart ***)
let layout =
    Layout(
        title = "Mt Bruno Elevation",
        autosize = false,
        margin =
            Margin(
                l = 65.,
                r = 50.,
                b = 65.,
                t = 90.
            )
    )

Surface(z = z)
|> Chart.Plot
|> Chart.WithLayout layout
|> Chart.WithWidth 700
|> Chart.WithHeight 500
|> Chart.Show
(*** include-it: chart ***)
```

I expect the figure bind in the widget not shown in web.

Comment: The library stop distributing WPF show helpers since version 1.4.0.See release notes. So, use old version or create helpers by yourself.